# Why is there a BodyParser and PlayBodyParser

Tags: playframework-2.6

The `Play` framework has `BodyParsers` and `PlayBodyParsers`. What is the purpose of have these two separately?

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.BodyParser

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.PlayBodyParsers

Answer (score 0):

The reason is "legacy". `BodyParsers` is a legacy body parsers trait. All this does is define a "parse" member with a PlayBodyParsers instance.

You can check it in the source code:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.x/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/BodyParsers.scala#L313